# Mysqli works from command line but not via HTML/Browser

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've got following Versions of apache and php:

```
apache2                   2.4.25-3+deb9u5
apache2-bin               2.4.25-3+deb9u5
apache2-data              2.4.25-3+deb9u5
apache2-utils             2.4.25-3+deb9u5
libapache2-mod-php7.0     7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php              1:7.0+49
php-common       1:49
php-mysql        1:7.0+49
php7.0           7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php7.0-cli       7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php7.0-common    7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php7.0-json      7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php7.0-mysql     7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php7.0-opcache   7.0.30-0+deb9u1
php7.0-readline  7.0.30-0+deb9u1
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hardware");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fp;";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
echo $num;

if ($num > 0)
        {
                echo "Ergebnis: <br>";
        }
else
        {
                echo "Keine Ergebnisse!<br>";
        }

while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
             echo $dsatz["hersteller"] . ", "
                . $dsatz["typ"] . ", "
                . $dsatz["gb"] . ", "
                . $dsatz["preis"] . ", "
                . $dsatz["artnummer"] . ", "
                . $dsatz["prod"] . "<br>";
        }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body></html>
```

The PHP code works properly from command line but not via Browser.
I figured out that the variable $num has no value when calling the php code via browser. It looks like there is no Database connection established.

I have no clue why.

P.S.:
php -i | grep mysqli   ----->     shows that mysqli is enabled

P.P.S.:
Mysqli result of webpage with `<?php phpinfo() ?>`
[image]

P.P.P.S: Logfiles (syslog, mysql/error.log, apache2/error.log) dont have entries during script call via browser.

Comment: You aren't describing your problem, beyond "it doesn't work." Have you tried enabling some more verbose error logging? You aren't checking the results of your statements to see if they're succeeding or not.

Comment: _"...shows that mysqli is enabled"_ <- shows that it's enabled for the command line. What about a web page with `<?php phpinfo() ?>`?

Comment: Thanks for the Info. To state it more obvious.

The script runs into the "else" statement which means that variable $num is < 0.
In command line the script works fine and outputs the database entries. (if statement)

Debugging the script lead to an empty $num variable when calling the script via browser. That means ther seems to be no database connection established.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Add this under connection ``if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }``

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you.
That gave me the error: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

which should be a permission error within mysql itself. I think I can fix it now.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Proper solution was as seeing in the comments:

Adding

```
if (!$con) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
```

to the script.
That lead to the errormessage:
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

The cause for this was the MariaDB mysql identification method "unix_socket" which didn't allow identification via browser script call.